# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for Jacobian

Tags: vector-analysis

Let $J_x$ denote the Jacobian operator of the function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$.

What is the proper statement of the fundamental theorem of calculus for this case?

That is can we write
\begin{align}
f(x_2)-f(x_1) =\int (J_x f) \cdot dx 
\end{align}

where $\int$ is some proper integral that integrates over a path from $x_1$ to $x_2$.

A reference would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may compare both sides component-wise and then it is simply the fundamental theorem of calculus for line integrals, i.e.,$$g(x_2)-g(x_1)=\int dg=\int\nabla g\cdot dx$$

Comment: By “Jacobian” do you mean the matrix of partial derivatives or the determinant of that matrix?

Comment: @amd Yes, the matrix of partial derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the Jacobian is involved in integration only when a change of variables is involved. For example, when changing from Cartesian to polar coordinates, you'd have $x = r \cos \theta$ and $y = r \sin \theta$. Instead of $dy dx$ as your integrating factor, you'd have the product of the Jacobian and $dr d\theta$.